# Fun with flows, getting null when converting to live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I am trying out flows and trying to see how they can be converted to mvvm with android view models. Here is what I tried first to test it out :

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var glucoseFlow: LiveData<Int>
    var _glucoseFlow = MutableLiveData<Int>()


    fun getGlucoseFlow() {
        glucoseFlow = flowOf(1,2).asLiveData()
        _glucoseFlow.value = glucoseFlow.value
    }
}


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView (
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel._glucoseFlow.observe(this, Observer {
            handleUpdate(it)
        })

        viewModel.getGlucoseFlow()
    }

    private fun handleUpdate(reading : Int) {
        glucose_reading.text = reading.toString()
    }
}
```

I get a null for the reading number however any ideas ?

Comment: "I get a null for the reading number" isn't enough information for your problem. Please add your expected behavior, what makes it fail and maybe add a complete test which proves your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to assign `glucoseFlow.value` to `_glucoseFlow.value` directly, I guess you should use a `MediatorLiveData<Int>`, however this is not my final suggestion.

You can solve it if you collect flow items and then assign them to your private variable.

```
// For private variables, prefer use underscore prefix, as well MutableLiveData for assignable values.
private val _glucoseFlow = MutableLiveData<Int>()
// For public variables, prefer use LiveData just to read values.
val glucoseFlow: LiveData<Int> get() = _glucoseFlow 

fun getGlucoseFlow() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        flowOf(1, 2)
            .collect {
                _glucoseFlow.value = it
            }
    }
}
```

Having the before implementation over the `HomeViewModel`, start to observe your public `glucoseFlow` from `HomeFragment` and you will be able to receive non-null sequence values (1 and then 2).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using databinding, do not forget **specify the fragment view as the lifecycle owner of the binding** so that the binding can observe LiveData updates.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
}
```